# highcharts expect point configuration to be numbbers or arrays in turbo mode error

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts export server version 3.1.1. I am getting this error in some of my reports. Can you help me?

I get the error in the picture when printing. The turbothreshold value is 1000, but when I reduce this value to 0, I get an error. I get the same error when I set it to max value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnRqK.png

The display error on the screen started to occur after upgrading the Highcharts export server version from 2.1.0 to 3.1.1. I ask for your support in this matter.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to help you without taking a look at your code. Could you reproduce this issue in an online editor I could work on? You can use this demo as a template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0pbeym97/